# how to add donut charts as a markers on a map in Shiny?

Tags: shiny, plotly, shiny-server, shinyapps, r-leaflet

I'm performing an app in Shiny.
Instead of having markers on the map, i wish it had a donut diagram for each location in order to observe the behavior of each location at the same time. I have a parameter (lambda) that when modified in a sidebar, the proportions in the donut chart change for each location.

These are the properties of each variable in my input

> str(datos_ciudades)
> 'data.frame':   240 obs. of  11 variables:
> $ pop_code      : chr  "CHB" "JPT" "CHS" "CDX" ...
> $ description   : chr  "Han Chinese in Bejing, China" "Japanese in Tokyo, Japan" "Southern Han Chinese" "Chinese Dai in Xishuanagbanna, China" ...
> $ continent_code: chr  "EAS" "EAS" "EAS" "EAS" ...
> $ city          : chr  "Bejing" "Tokyo" "Changsha" "Yunnan" ...
> $ data_set      : chr  "1000 Genomes" "1000 Genomes" "1000 Genomes" "1000 Genomes" ...
> $ Latitud       : num  39.9 35.7 28.2 24.3 10.8 ...
> $ Longitud      : num  116 140 113 103 107 ...
> $ Lambda        : num  0.025 0.025 0.025 0.025 0.025 0.025 0.025 0.025 0.025 0.025 ...
> $ C1            : num  0.387 0.342 0.376 0.271 0.242 ...
> $ C2            : num  0.488 0.517 0.484 0.423 0.332 ...
> $ C3            : num  0.125 0.141 0.14 0.306 0.426 ...

#My script runs well, just I need overlay the donut charts on the map

```
#Libraries
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(plotly)

# upload df with cities information
datos_ciudades<-read.csv("cities_info_random.csv", header = T)
str(datos_ciudades)
# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Interactive Map"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("ubicacion", "Select a population:",
                  choices = unique(datos_ciudades$description)),
      selectInput("lambda", "Select a value of lambda:",
                  choices = unique(datos_ciudades$Lambda))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("mapa"),
      plotlyOutput("diagramaDonut") 
    )
  )
)

# Definir el servidor
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$mapa <- renderLeaflet({
    ubicacion_seleccionada <- input$ubicacion
    data <- datos_ciudades[datos_ciudades$description == ubicacion_seleccionada, ]
    pal <- colorFactor(c("#0033FF", "#FF0000"), domain = c("1000 Genomes", "HGDP"))
    leaflet(datos_ciudades) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(
        lat = ~Latitud,
        lng = ~Longitud,
        label = ~description,
        radius = 5,
        opacity = 0.2,
        color = ~pal (data_set),
        popup = ~paste("Población:", description,
                       "<br>Data set:", data_set,
                       "<br>Population code:", pop_code,
                       "<br>Continental code:", continent_code)
                      
      ) %>%
      addLegend(
        "bottomright",
        colors = c("#0033FF", "#FF0000"),
        labels = c("1000 Genomes", "HGDP"),
        title = "Populations"
      )
  })
  
  output$diagramaDonut <- renderPlotly({
    ubicacion_seleccionada <- input$ubicacion
    lambda_selected <- as.numeric(input$lambda)
    
    data <- datos_ciudades[datos_ciudades$description == ubicacion_seleccionada &
                             datos_ciudades$Lambda == lambda_selected, ]
    
    c1_value <- data$C1
    c2_value <- data$C2
    c3_value <- data$C3
    
    plot_ly(labels = c("Community 1", "Community 2", "Community 3"),
            values = c(c1_value, c2_value, c3_value),
            type = 'pie', textfont = list(size = 18), hole = 0.4, width = 460, height = 460) %>%
      layout(title = paste("Proportion of individuals <br>by community in",ubicacion_seleccionada,
                           "<br>setting a lambda =", lambda_selected), legend = list(x = 1.1, y = 0.5))
  })
}

# Ejecutar la aplicación
shinyApp(ui, server)
```